# Count the number of list elements on page that have an id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list and I want to count only the items in that list that have an id attribute. For example, this is my code:

```
<ul class="members-list">
  <li id="newmember1"></li> 
  <li id="newmember2"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="3"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="4"></li>
</ul>
```

The list counts how many members are associated with an account and a user can add and delete members themselves. When they add a member, they are given an id. I want to count the number of unused accounts they have, i.e. the list items here that aren't associated with an id (the bottom 2).

I have the following code already to count how many list items altogether:

```
var listOfMembers = $(".members-list").children();
var numberOfMembers = listOfMembers.length;
```

However I don't know how to get the ones that don't have an id, and separate them from the group? I'm not even sure if this is possible, but would really grateful for any pointers please :)

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you.

```
var listOfMembers = $(".members-list").find("li[id]")
```

Comment: *i.e. the list items here that aren't associated with an id (the bottom 2)*!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll()`:

```
let count = document.querySelectorAll('ul li[id]').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) with `:not()`

```js
var listOfMembers = $(".members-list").find(":not(li[id])");
var numberOfMembers = listOfMembers.length;
console.log(numberOfMembers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="members-list">
  <li id="newmember1"></li> 
  <li id="newmember2"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="3"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="4"></li>
</ul>
```

**OR:** You can use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out the elements not having an *id* attribute.

```js
var listOfMembers = $(".members-list li").filter((_, el) =>  !$(el).attr('id'));
var numberOfMembers = listOfMembers.length;
console.log(numberOfMembers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="members-list">
  <li id="newmember1"></li> 
  <li id="newmember2"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="3"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="4"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. This can be done using the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector combined with targeting all li's with an `id` attribute.

```js
$(function() {
  var listItems = $('li:not([id])');

  console.log(listItems.get(), 'Number of elements: ' + listItems.length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="members-list">
  <li id="newmember1"></li>
  <li id="newmember2"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="3"></li>
  <li data-empty-index="4"></li>
</ul>
```